# What's the best way to initialize shared members in a class in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, constructor, shared

I was looking on the Internet to see if there were any good examples on how to initialize shared members within a class while still initializing instance variables. I did find an expression that might fit to the answer:

```
Shared Sub New()
    'Declare shared members
End Sub
```

But you also have the standard

```
Sub New()
    'Declare instance members
End Sub
```

How do I initialize both instance and shared members without re-initializing the shared members every time an object is created from a class?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Shared Sub New` (also known as a *type constructor*) is executed only once for each type (within an AppDomain, that is), so any member initialization in there will not be be repeated for each instance.